# GitHub Actions trigger job based on content of comment

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to manually trigger the deploy job based on the content of a comment on a PR. I have the following yaml in my workflows, but this does not seem to do anything when I comment "deploy":

```yaml
name: Adapter Deploy
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created, edited]
jobs:
  build-and-deploy-to-Azure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.comment.body == 'deploy'
    steps:
    - name: 'Confirm manual deploy'
      run: echo I was run on demand by ${GITHUB_ACTOR}
```

I have no idea how to debug this or what is wrong my yaml. Could someone help me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the Action run? Maybe add an unconditional step that prints the `github` object to check its content.

Comment: The documentation says the workflow file will be only triggered if it is committed to the default branch. Is this your case maybe? Please refer to the documentation https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#issue_comment

Comment: `if: ${{ github.event.comment.body == 'deploy' }}` ?